# R: Creating many new data frames with unique values from dataset until no duplicates left, loop?

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates

I am using R to repeatedly split my dataset to extract unique values and duplicate values into separate data frames to the point where I won't have any data frames with duplicate values in, so I end up with many data frames over the number of iterations required to do this, continuously using the previous dataframe generated.

Quite hard to explain but here is an example:

```
df1 <- data.frame(name = c("michelle", "sarah", "amy", "lauren", "susan", "sarah", "michelle", "michelle"),
                  var1 = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1"))

df2 <- df1[!duplicated(df1[, "name"]),]
df2duplicates <- df1[duplicated(df1[, "name"]),]

df3 <- df2duplicates[!duplicated(df2duplicates[, "name"]),]
df3duplicates <- df2duplicates[duplicated(df2duplicates[, "name"]),]

df4 <- df3duplicates[!duplicated(df3duplicates[, "name"]),]
df4duplicates <- df3duplicates[duplicated(df3duplicates[, "name"]),]
```

And so on.....

It's basically repeating the same thing but just using the previous data frame created, so I have struggled to put into a loop etc. but I would really like to make this code more streamlined instead of repeating the same lines over and over.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: maybe a recursive function that has an adequate stop condition?

Comment: or a while loop. Like while duplicates exist, continue to subset etc

Answer (score 0):

I ended up going for a different approach. Here is what I did if anyone is interested:

```
    library(tidyverse)
df1<- df1 %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(Count = row_number()) %>% 
  mutate(totaldup = n()) 

for(i in 1:50) {
  test <- subset(df1, Count==i) 
  assign(paste("dfsub",i, sep=""), test) 
}
```